# How to determine used ckeditor configuration

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

i have a custom ckeditor plugin with a custom dialog.
The dialog is added like this:

```
    var dialog_file = this.path + 'dialogs/customdialog.js' ;
    CKEDITOR.dialog.add( pluginName, dialog_file);
```

I would like to determine in the dialog which ckeditor config is loaded. I can make assumptions based on that and set the variables accordingly. Is that possible?

It would also be possible to add a new config variable and check it or something similar. But how can i access the config variable from the custom dialog?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the initialization of the dialog you get as a parameter the editor that it's calling it, and then you can read `editor.config`